# How to create a Custom Option menu in HTML5/jQuery for Android App?

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova

I want to create an option menu for my Android application. I'm using HTML5 and jQuery Mobile with Phonegap. I found the solution using Java but I want to be able to do this using HTML5/jQuery/PhoneGap. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: you cant expect many answers until that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to add new div outside the jquery-mobile framework.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('.show-menu').click(trigger_menu);
        });

        function trigger_menu()
        {
            $('#menu').slideToggle(500);
        }

        $(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
            $(document).click(function(e) {
                if(e.srcElement.className != 'show-menu ui-link'){
                    $('#menu').slideUp(500);
                }
            });

            $('#menu').click(function(){
                $('#menu').slideUp(500);
            });
        });

        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
        }

        function onMenuKeyDown() {
            trigger_menu();
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="onLoad()">
    <div data-role="page" id="page">   
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page One</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">    
            <a href="#" class="show-menu">Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Menu (outside mobile framework) -->
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="next.html">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS file is :

```
/* CSS Document */
#menu {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:9999;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#CCCCCC;
    width:100%;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#menu ul li {
    border-bottom:1px #FFFFFF solid;
    padding:15px;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
    background-color:#C60;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}

#menu ul li a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if u have a phonegap app why dont u use jquery mobile menus and ways to display such stuff?
[Jquery Mobile demos](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/)

Comment: I'm not saying about menus. I'm saying about option menus when menubutton in clicked.

Comment: attach an image to your question as to what u exactly want

Comment: Sorry! I don't have enough permission to upload image. The similar example is in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html. But I want same in HTML5.

Comment: u can try the fixed footer menus of jquery mobile. not the same, but quite close.

Answer (score 0):

you should create/override the method onCreateOptionsMenu like this
one:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add([some arguments here]);
    //...add more menu options...
    return true;
}
```

and to handle the selections, override

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case OK_MENU_ITEM:
            showMsg("Ok");
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: This in Java. I need in HTML5/jQuery/phonegap. Can this code be integrated in HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you were looking for this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton
Not sure if you are still looking.